# Checking arduino code with multimeter

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

When we upload the code on arduino ,sometimes we do not get the desired results.
I saw a friend of mine doing the test on arduino using a multimeter to make sure that the code is right.

He said that we can make sure the code is right by checking the voltages on carious i/o pins on arduino. Like if the voltage on i/o pins is less than 5 V then the code is having some error,and also if we chckt the voltage on RX and Tx pins it should be 0.29 V.

I know question posted by me is not clear, but this is something which worked but i was not able to understand it properly.

So if anybody can deduce what this means and how it is done so, please proide an answer?

Comment: Sometimes your code will result in specific external effects and events. You check to see if the results you get are the results you expected. But this is normal debugging procedure, and not particular to the Arduino platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main things to test with your multimeter: the voltage of the power to the Arduino (between 5v and Gnd), and the voltage of the IO pins (between them and Gnd).

- Voltage of the power supply simply tells you if the Arduino is powered up correctly, if its power management circuits or power supply have failed, you'll be able to pick it up here.
- Voltage of the outputs should be either 5v or 0v, relative to ground. By testing the voltage on a pin you can tell whether it is being written high (5v) or low (0v) by the Arduino, hence seeing what the code is doing to the pins.

I should make it clear that there is no right or wrong way to tell if the code in general is working based on the voltage of the pins.